# Copy image from JavaFX application and paste it using Windows

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, javafx-8

I am working on a JavaFX application. I want to copy image from application using context menu and paste it using Windows feature of paste.

```
 File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\my\\mysql.gif");
    Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
    ImageView ive =new ImageView(image);
    cm = new ContextMenu();
 MenuItem copy = new MenuItem("Copy");
 cm.getItems().add(copy);
 copy.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            //Paste Image at location
            Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putImage(image); // the image you want, as javafx.scene.image.Image
            clipboard.setContent(content);
        }
    });
```

For example, like shown below in images.

[image: Copy Image From aaplication]

And want to paste at location from using of Windows features menu.

[image: Paste Image at spectific location]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Clipboard`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html) and [`ClipboardContent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/ClipboardContent.html), e.g. as:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
// for paste as image, e.g. in GIMP
content.putImage(image); // the image you want, as javafx.scene.image.Image
// for paste as file, e.g. in Windows Explorer
content.putFiles(java.util.Collections.singletonList(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\my\\mysql.gif")));
clipboard.setContent(content);
```

For the "Paste" operation of Windows context menus to work, the clipboard content has to be `File`. In the case demonstrated above, this is easy, otherwise a temporary file should be created.

Comment: i tried it but its not working. i am edited above question. check it. paste option not comes

Comment: You simply have to put a file in the clipboard for this case, see edit.

Comment: This is working for Gimp and Paint but it's not working in Microsoft Word.. Do you have any ideas? But it's working for Microsoft Powerpoint..

Comment: Maybe try the `ClipboardContent.putImage()` method?